# Дождаться полной загрузки страницы после перехода

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, яндекс-музыка

Целевой сайт для расширения [Яндекс.Музыка](https://music.yandex.ru). Когда первый раз загружаешь страницу или обновляешь ее, дождаться полной загрузки можно через код:

```
window.onload = function(){}
```

Но когда сайт уже загрузился и ты выполняешь переходы по разделам, он не обновляется целиком. Шапка остается неизменной, а остальное содержимое обновляется внутри будто отдельный фрейм или вкладка. И событие полной загрузки не срабатывает.

Как отследить полную загрузку после таких "внутренних" переходов по сайту?

Вариант с отслеживанием изменения адреса не подходит, потому что он меняется моментально, загрузка к этому времени еще не заканчивается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент пришел к решению через таймер.

`background.js` сообщает о завершении загрузки (не полной)

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                event: 'complete'
            })
        }
    }
);
```

`content.js` получив сообщение запускает функцию `fillContent()`. Она идентифицирует адрес страницы и вызывает таймер `waitPageFullLoaded()`, который будет ждать появления уникального для данной страницы элемента. После появления, таймер удаляется и вызывается callback-функция, которая уже делает требуемую задачу на полностью загруженной странице.

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.event == 'complete') {
            fillContent()
        }
    });

function fillContent() {
    url = location.href.split('/')
    if (url.length == 7 && url[5] == 'playlists') {
        waitPageFullLoaded('.page-playlist__tracks-list', modifyPagePlaylist)
    }
    else if (...) { ...}
}

function waitPageFullLoaded(uniqueClass, callback) {
    let timerId = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.querySelector(uniqueClass) != null) {
            clearInterval(timerId)
            callback()
        }
    }, 500)
}
```